Who can still castle?
Here is a new retrograde chess puzzle! This one shouldn't be all too difficult, so please feel free to have a go:
Who can still castle here?

(To be precise: Your task is, for each of the possible castling rights, to figure out if it is possible to reach this position in such a way that the right is still intact.)
Please provide your reasoning in your answer. Have fun! :)

Got me, had to delete my answer. rot13(Frrzf yvxr guvf cbfvgvba vf abg ernpunoyr ng nyy, ohg lbh jbhyqa'g cbfg fhpu n gevpx dhrfgvba, jbhyq lbh?) :-)

Great puzzle +1!!

This is an excellent & surprising retro! Looks so innocent a position

I'm going to go with

 Neither can castle

because the "this shouldn't be difficult" is a complete and utter lie, and the only way to reach this position legally is to

 bring the white queen to c6.

Yeah.
(EDIT: turns out this is not actually true, but because the setter is way too clever, it's actually "close enough" and everything that follows is still very relevant. See the edited-in "but wait" section at the end for details on the exception, but for now, let's imagine no such exception exists.)
Here's why:
The bishop at c8 cannot be the promoted a-pawn, because only three black pieces are missing.
The only way that bishop can ever reach c8 is if black moves the d7 pawn before the e-pawn. (After the e-pawn moves, the route is irrevocably blocked.)
But the d-pawn's move must be a capture, so what was captured on c6? It cannot have been white's a-pawn: with all the black pawns in their starting positions, the white pawn has no way to reach the c-file.
So the captured piece must have been a rook, a knight or a queen. (The original light square bishop is still on the board)
But if a white piece gets captured, the a-pawn must promote to replace it, which is where things get really interesting:
The promotion must happen on d8 exactly, and the very first move of the a-pawn must be a capture: else it cannot take black's light square bishop, without which it's impossible for the pawn to reach the d-file
This means that the captured piece cannot have been the a1 rook, as the a2 pawn was still blocking the way at that time.
The captured piece cannot have been the h1 rook either: the promotion is only possible after black's e-pawn has moved (the f8 bishop needs to get out and be captured), so white's bishop must be at c8 at that time. This means that white must already have played g3, which blocks the way back to h1 for the promoted rook.
Also, the captured piece wasn't a knight. Since the promotion can only occur once black has made both the pawn moves, the promoted knight would be forever stuck on d8 with zero non-capturing moves possible. This is so ridiculously delightful it's hard to believe.
So the only piece that can have been at c6 for black's d-pawn to capture is the queen, and for the queen to get there,

 white's king must have moved.

Since the white pawn must promote at d8, it must pass though d7 on the way, so

 the black king must obviously have moved, too.

Here's a sample game:

 1. g3 Nh6 2. Bh3 Ng8 3. Kf1 Nh6 4. Kg2 Ng8 5. Kf3 Nh6 6. Ke3 Ng8 7. Qf1 Nh6 8. Qg2 Ng8 9. Qc6 dxc6 10. Bg4 Be6 11. Bh3 Bb3 12. Bc8 Qd5 13. axb3 Qc4 14. bxc4 e6 15. c5 Bd6 16. cxd6 Nf6 17. d7+ Kf8 18. d8=Q+ Ne8 19. Qd5 Nf6 20. Qg2 Ke8 21. Qf1 Ng8 22. Qd1 Nh6 23. Kf3 Ng8 24. Kg2 Nh6 25. Kf1 Ng8 26. Ke1 Nh6 27. h3 Ng8 28. h4


BUT WAIT:
Couldn't you do a full switcharoo with the promoted a-pawn and the two rooks? As in, bring the h1 rook to c6, then take a piece or two with the a-pawn, bring the a1 rook to h1 while the route is open, and only then bring the bishop to c8?
The answer is a resounding

 Yes!

You can definitely reach this position that way too, so the white king hasn't necessarily moved after all.

 But if the king hasn't moved, then both the white rooks have, and castling is still impossible.

That's a bit much, there should be an upper limit on how brilliant a chess puzzle can be :-)

Very well done! You found out every little trick :)

WOW, Bass and @Tim. What a puzzle and solution(s)!

I don't think I've seen a castling problem where both branches of the castling condition (on one side) are involved. (Although I've seen answers like "either side can castle, but not both") I guess the only way to beat this brilliant "upper limit" is to somehow involve these branches on both sides.

Great solution to a fine problem!

It seems that this position cannot be reached with legal moves. The whites are missing only the a pawn, which means that the only way black's d pawn could get on the c file is by capturing that pawn. But the only way for the a pawn to get to the c file is to make two captures itself, which must be black's bishops or queen. It cannot be the light-square bishop because in order for it to get out, the d7 square must be already empty. This means, the black dark-square bishop and the queen must have moved out before the d pawn moved, but for that the  e pawn must have moved first. But that would make it impossible for the white bishop to get to the last rank because the e pawn is blocking the white diagonal. Therefore, I don't think this position is in principle possible even assuming that either the king or some of the rooks have moved.

Welcome to puzzling stackexchange :) Your answer gets at some vital points but is not quite there. The position is certainly reachable :)

Here's another sample game in which both Kings have moved, the a pawn did not promote and the bishop on c8 is the original:

1. g3 Nh6 2. Bh3 Ng8 3. Kf1 Nh6 4. Kg2 Ng8 5. Kf3 Nh6 6. Qf1 Ng8 7. Qg2 Nh6 8. Ke3 Ng8 9. Qc6 dxc6 10. Kf3 Be6 11. Kg2 Bxa2 12. Kf1 Be6 13. Ke1 Qd7 14. Nf3 Kd8 15. Bxe6 Ke8 16. h4 Nh6 17. Ng1 Ng8 18. Bxd7+ Kd8 19. Bc8 Ke8


Oops! Forgot that the White queen has to be present.
